# Difference between equivalence and isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

I have a question. Could someone explain to me what is the difference between equivalence of categories and isomoprhism of categories? Until now I thought that it is the same thing. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Any text would explain that. Did you try Mac Lane? Or any other text?

Comment: I am reading Awodey

Comment: An equivalence of categories does not have to be an isomorphism on the classes of objects. There is an equivalent of categories between the category $\mathbf{1}$ (with one object and identity morphism) and any category that has a unique morphism between any of its objects. Such equivalence of categories is not an isomorphism unless the second category has exactly one object.